# How to make distributed join of three or more tables as local join?

Tags: clickhouse

I am mainly confused about the execution plan of three tables, this is the execution plan of query as below(note: t1d,t2d,t3d are distributed table):

```sql
select xxx
from t1d t1d
left join 
    (select * from t2d where xxx group by xxx) t2d 
using A
left join
    (select * from t3d where xxx group by xxx) t3d
using A
where t1d.xxx
group by t1d.xxx
SETTINGS distributed_product_mode='local'
```

```sh
┌─explain───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Expression (Projection)                                                                           │
│   CreatingSets (Create sets before main query execution)                                          │
│     Expression (Before ORDER BY)                                                                  │
│       Join (JOIN)                                                                                 │
│         Expression ((Before JOIN + Projection))                                                   │
│           SettingQuotaAndLimits (Set limits and quota after reading from storage)                 │
│             Union                                                                                 │
│               Expression ((Convert block structure for query from local replica + ))              │
│                 CreatingSets (Create sets before main query execution)                            │
│                   Expression (Before ORDER BY)                                                    │
│                     AddingDelayedSource (Add non-joined rows after JOIN)                          │
│                       Join (JOIN)                                                                 │
│                         Expression (Before JOIN)                                                  │
│                           SettingQuotaAndLimits (Set limits and quota after reading from storage) │
│                             ReadFromPreparedSource (Read from NullSource)                         │
│                   CreatingSet (Create set for JOIN)                                               │
│                     Expression ((Projection + Before ORDER BY))                                   │
│                       Aggregating                                                                 │
│                         Expression (Before GROUP BY)                                              │
│                           SettingQuotaAndLimits (Set limits and quota after reading from storage) │
│                             ReadFromStorage (MergeTree)                                           │
│               ReadFromPreparedSource (Read from remote replica)                                   │
│     CreatingSet (Create set for JOIN)                                                             │
│       Expression (Projection)                                                                     │
│         SettingQuotaAndLimits (Set limits and quota after reading from storage)                   │
│           Union                                                                                   │
│             Expression ((Convert block structure for query from local replica + Before ORDER BY)) │
│               SettingQuotaAndLimits (Set limits and quota after reading from storage)             │
│                 ReadFromStorage (MergeTree)                                                       │
│             ReadFromPreparedSource (Read from remote replica)                                     │
```

From my understanding, I think the step as below:

1. t1_local and t2_local do local join on each shard as your reply, and I use explain syntax to find that t2d is written to t2_local, it is true, I am clear about this.
2. Initiator host combines the results from all shard of local join
3. each shard do query "select * from t3_local where xxx group by xxx" and combines on the initiator(maybe this is synchronized with step1)
4. Initiator do join between result of step2 and result of step3.

and my question is that: I hope on each shard can do local join like

```sql
select xxx
from t1_local 
left join (select xxx from t2_local)
using A
left join (select xxx from t3_local)
using A
```

and then the initiator combines results from all shards.
I think this is faster than above. But actually the execution plan can't show it.

Answer (score 11):

How does `JOIN`s work at Clickhouse?

I'll try to explain with an example of joining 2 tables.

**ALGORITHM**

Let's assume each shard has a *local_table* and *distributed* wrapper over it.

When you join *distributed_table* with other table (e.g. subquery):

```sql
SELECT <fields> FROM distributed_table JOIN (SELECT * FROM some_other_table) USING field
```

1. Initiator host sends query to each shard with left table replaced by the corresponding local table:

```sql
SELECT <fields> FROM local_table JOIN (SELECT * FROM some_other_table) USING field
```

2. Every shard executes the subquery:

```sql
SELECT * FROM some_other_table
```

3. `local_table` is joined with previous result of each shard
4. Results are sent to the initiator host from all the shards
5. Initiator host combines the results

Let's take a look at an example and play around with the *distributed_product_mode* setting and local/distributed tables

**EXAMPLE**

Say we have a cluster `cluster_name` of two shards: *host1* and *host2*. Let's create tables there:

```sql
CREATE TABLE source_local ON CLUSTER cluster_name
(
    `key` Int32,
    `value` String
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/{shard}/default.source_local', '{replica}')
ORDER BY key;

CREATE TABLE source ON CLUSTER cluster_name AS source_local
ENGINE = Distributed(cluster_name, default, source_local)
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE to_join_local ON CLUSTER cluster_name
(
    `key` Int32,
    `value` String
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/{shard}/default.to_join_local', '{replica}')
ORDER BY key;

CREATE TABLE to_join ON CLUSTER cluster_name AS to_join_local
ENGINE = Distributed(cluster_name, default, to_join_local)
```

Then, perform several insert at *host1*:

```sql
INSERT INTO source_local VALUES (1, 'source1'), (2, 'source2');
INSERT INTO to_join_local VALUES (1, 'tojoin1');
```

And one insert at *host2*:

```sql
INSERT INTO to_join_local VALUES (2, 'tojoin2');
```

For better understanding let's visualize local tables:

[image: Shard 1 and Shard 2 local tables]

Let's start with the basic configuration of*distributed_product_mode* setting, setting it just to `allow`. It will not modify the algorithm but also will not throw unnecessary exceptions:

```
SET distributed_product_mode = 'allow'
```

**JOINING WITH THE DISTRIBUTED TABLE**

```sql
SELECT
    source.key,
    source.value,
    to_join.value
FROM source AS source
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM to_join AS tj
) AS to_join USING (key)
```

***Short explanation:*** Every host perfoms join of left local table with right subquery and then results are combined at the initiator host.

Let's do this step by step according to the **algorithm**

1. The following query is sent to the shards:

```sql
SELECT
    source.key,
    source.value,
    to_join.value
FROM source_local AS source
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM to_join AS tj
) AS to_join USING (key)
```

*(note: `source` table is replaced by `source_local` table)*

2. All the shards executes the same subquery:

```sql
SELECT * FROM to_join AS tj
```

Since it is a Distributed table, the result will be the same on both of the shards:

```
┏━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ key ┃ value   ┃
┡━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━┩
│   1 │ tojoin1 │
├─────┴─────────┤
│   2 │ tojoin2 │
└─────┴─────────┘
```

3. `source_local` table joins this result on every shard.

***Host1***: `source_local` contains both rows with keys `1` and `2`, exactly as a result of the subquery. So the result of the join on host1 will contain 2 rows.

***Host2***: since `source_local` contains nothing on host2, result of the join will be empty.

Visualization:

[image: Local joins]
4-5. These result transferred to the initiator and combined there.
The final result:

```
┏━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ key ┃ value   ┃ to_join.value ┃
┡━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│   1 │ source1 │ tojoin1       │
├─────┼─────────┼───────────────┤
│   2 │ source2 │ tojoin2       │
└─────┴─────────┴───────────────┘
```

**JOINING WITH THE LOCAL TABLE**

```sql
SELECT
    source.key,
    source.value,
    to_join.value
FROM source AS source
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM to_join_local AS tj
) AS to_join USING (key)
```

***Short explanation:*** Each shard performs join of two local tables and then results are combined on the initiator

1. The following query is sent to the shards:

```sql
SELECT
    source.key,
    source.value,
    to_join.value
FROM source_local AS source
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM to_join_local AS tj
) AS to_join USING (key)
```

2-3. [image]
4-5. The final result therefore differs from the previous one:

```
┏━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ key ┃ value   ┃ to_join.value ┃
┡━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│   1 │ source1 │ tojoin1       │
└─────┴─────────┴───────────────┘
```

I think this request should solve your issue

**JOIN WITH DISTRIBUTED TABLE , distributed_product_mode = 'local'**

```sql
SELECT
    source.key,
    source.value,
    to_join.value
FROM source AS source
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM to_join AS tj
) AS to_join USING (key)
SETTINGS distributed_product_mode = 'local'
```

The result:

```
┌─key─┬─value───┬─to_join.value─┐
│   1 │ source1 │ tojoin1       │
└─────┴─────────┴───────────────┘
```

We perfomed join with the Distributed table, but got the same result as for joining with local table.
The reason is that `distributed_product_mode = 'local'` Clickhouse implicitly does the same as we did when joining with local table. Here are the [docs](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#distributed-product-mode)

This join also performs as you want

**JOIN WITH DISTRIBUTED TABLE , distributed_product_mode = 'global'**

The same query:

```sql
SELECT
    source.key,
    source.value,
    to_join.value
FROM source AS source
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM to_join AS tj
) AS to_join USING (key)
SETTINGS distributed_product_mode = 'global'
```

results in:

```
┌─key─┬─value───┬─to_join.value─┐
│   1 │ source1 │ tojoin1       │
│   2 │ source2 │ tojoin2       │
└─────┴─────────┴───────────────┘
```

We've the same result as is in the first case with *Distributed* table. Are there any difference?
Yeah, there is a difference in a way Clickhouse performs the query:

At the point **2** right subquery will be executed ***only at one shard*** and then it will be spreaded across other shards. It can be used for query optimizations, but do no affect the result.
You can achive the same result by using [`GLOBAL JOIN`](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/join/#global-join) instead of `JOIN`.

Comment: I edit my question because this can support markdown format and no character limitation. And I can't post an answer myself. I am not sure if you can receive remind. JFYI

Comment: What do you think about this?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this query should work as you expected, but I prefer to accomplish this without the *distributed_product_mode* setting.

I can assume that you are joining 3 Distributed tables: t1d, t2d, t3d.
Clickhouse will work as you expected: it will execute your request on each shard locally and then combine results at initiator.

That means that you can use join of the Distributed table with local tables to achieve expected result:

```
SELECT xxx
FROM t1d t1d
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM t2d_local WHERE xxx GROUP BY xxx) t2d 
USING A
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM t3d_local WHERE xxx GROUP BY xxx) t3d
USING A
WHERE t1d.xxx
GROUP BY t1d.xxx
```

Change *t2d_local* and *t3d_local* with the corresponding local tables

Answer (score 0):

I do this with a subquery.

For example, table t1d, t2d, t3d are distributed table, and i have a query like this:

```
SELECT t1d.a,
       t2d.b,
       t3d.c
FROM t1d
INNER JOIN t2d ON t1d.id = t2d.id
INNER JOIN t3d ON t2d.id = t3d.id;
```

so change the sql to this:

```
set distributed_product_mode = 'local';

SELECT t1d.a,
       t2d.b,
       t3d.c
FROM t1d
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT t2d.*, t3d.*
   FROM t2d
   INNER JOIN t3d ON t2d.id = t3d.id)bc ON t1d.id = bc.id;
```

then it can go with local join on each shard.

NOTICE: join key and sharding_key must be the same column.